# PHP send out HTML email

Tags: php, html

I am creating a app that sends HTML emails that are stored in database. I use PHP to dynamically create a drop down menu which hold the name of every template available on database.

the html code is in a column called temp_html and stored a raw html, I am trying to add this code to option value like:

```
$form.= '<option id="'.$result['temp_id'].'"value="'.$result['temp_html'].'">"'.$result['temp_name'].'"</option>';
```

now i need to add the selected option value into a `$message` variable which is added into `mail()` function.

And this is where I am getting lost how do I add the selected option value into a variable and if user changes their mind and different template befores sending will the variable get updated with new html code...?

html code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Mail</h2>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">Send To:
        <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient">
        <br>Subject:
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
        <br />

            <?php require( 'mail.php'); echo LoadTemplate(); ?>
            <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Send" name='submit'>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

php code:

```
  <?php
function LoadTemplate(){
    require('connect_db.php');
    $sql = "SELECT temp_id, temp_name, temp_html FROM templates WHERE temp_id=temp_id";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $form='<select id="template" name="template">';
            $form.='<option value="">Select Template</option>';
                while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $form.= '<option id="'.$result['temp_id'].'"value="'.$result['temp_html'].'">"'.$result['temp_name'].'"</option>';
                }

    $form.='</select>';
    return $form; 
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $to = $_POST['recipient'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    var_dump($message);
    //$message = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['template'], "r") or exit("Unable to open file");
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $mail_send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if($mail_send){
     echo 'Mail Send ';
     }else{
     echo 'Try Later';
     }
}
?>
```

I am using LoadTemplate function to deal with what I am trying to achieve

could someone suggest how I should go about achieve what I am trying to do

Comment: I don't get your question, what's the error?

Comment: there is no error, what i am trying do to is to pick up HTML stored in option value save it in a $message variable and use it in mail() to send email